# Property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-reactivity

While trying out Vue and Vuex, i stumbled upon the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I fail to understand and solve this issue, mainly because `msg` is defined in the code under `data`. It's probably doesn't related directly to Vuex, but i faced it only when i started using Vuex.

Here is my code:

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { store } from './store.js'

Vue.component('app',  App);

var vApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-text="msg"></div>
    <input id="name-b" class="input" v-model="nameB" type="text" placeholder="Name B">
  </div>
</template>

<script type = "text/javascript">
  module.exports = {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
      return {
        msg: 'boooo'
      }
    },
computed: {
  return {
    nameB: {
      get() {
          this.$store.state.nameB
        },
        set(value) {
          this.$store.commit('setName', value);
        }
    },
  } 
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    nameB: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    setName: function(state, name) { state.locationName = name},
  },
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It was a curly brackets issue and possibly the `return` in `computed` that is not needed...

This is a confusing error message.